# Add Marker Label to google maps marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
        
        var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
    authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
    storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
  };
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        }
        
        //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
        var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
        
        // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
        var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
      </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
      // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
      // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
      // locate you.
      var map, infoWindow;
      var lat, lng;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 18

        });
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lng = position.coords.longitude;
            var pos = {lat: lat, lng: lng };
                _setGeoFire();
              var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var markerLabel = 'Go';

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lat: data.User.l[0],
      lng: data.User.l[1]


    },
    map: map
    label: markerLabel
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
  marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
    return function(e) {
      infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
  }(data)));
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
          
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
      function _setGeoFire(){
    geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng]).then(()=>{
            console.log("Location added");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
    </script>
    <script 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need help with adding a label to a google map marker. It keeps coming up with an error that says unexpected identifier.https://medium.com/@barvysta/google-marker-api-lets-play-level-1-dynamic-label-on-marker-f9b94f2e3585. I used this website tutorial to make the marker label. I dont know if there was an error in the tutorial or something If anyone could help me with this that would be great[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {
    lat: data.User.l[0],
    lng: data.User.l[1]
  },
  map: map,
  label: markerLabel
});
```

You forgot to put a comma after map: map,

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on line 93:

```
92:     map: map   // <------------- missing comma
93      label: markerLabel  //<----- unexpected identifier
```

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier js:93`

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Geolocation</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <!-- Place this inside the HTML head; don't use async defer for now -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/geofire/4.1.2/geofire.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    var config = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyCWZjRe2CK8Hu2VN35AgZOQ7lQZKcI-UWM",
      authDomain: "carrier-35d7c.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://carrier-35d7c.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "carrier-35d7c",
      storageBucket: "carrier-35d7c.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "827792028763"
    };
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    }

    //Create a node at firebase location to add locations as child keys
    var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");

    // Create a new GeoFire key under users Firebase location
    var geoFire = new GeoFire(locationsRef.push());
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    // Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
    // prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
    // failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
    // locate you.
    var map, infoWindow;
    var lat, lng;

    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
          lat: -34.397,
          lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 18

      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      // Try HTML5 geolocation.
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lng = position.coords.longitude;
          var pos = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng
          };
          _setGeoFire();
          var locationsRef = firebase.database().ref("locations");
          locationsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            var data = snapshot.val();
            var markerLabel = 'Go';

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: {
                lat: data.User.l[0],
                lng: data.User.l[1]


              },
              map: map,
              label: markerLabel
            });
            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
            marker.addListener('click', (function(data) {
              return function(e) {
                infowindow.setContent(this.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>" + data.User.g);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
              }
            }(data)));
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
          });

          infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
          infoWindow.setContent('Current Location');
          infoWindow.open(map);
          map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function() {
          handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
      } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      }
    }

    function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      infoWindow.open(map);
    }

    function _setGeoFire() {
      geoFire.set("User", [lat, lng]).then(() => {
        console.log("Location added");
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD2nPlSt_nM7PSKD8So8anbUbBYICFWcCA&callback=initMap">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```